# Create an stored (and automated) procedure for External Tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, datatables, oracle-sqldeveloper, external

Firstly, thank you in advance for your answers.

This question is about External Tables and procedures.

I will have some .csv files stored in a directory and I have to add all these data stored in a table.

My idea is:

1. Loading csv file data into an External Table
2. Insert all data from External Table into the Final Table

I already created the code to load data from the **csv file** to the **External Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE "INFO"."DEVICE_EXTERNAL"
    (
        "Serial Number" VARCHAR2(100),
        "Status" VARCHAR2(100),
        "Install Date" VARCHAR2(100)
        )
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
        ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
          DEFAULT DIRECTORY "ER_IN_FILES"
          ACCESS PARAMETERS
          (   RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline 
              SKIP 1 
              FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
              optionally enclosed BY '"' 
              MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
              (
                "Serial Number" char,
                "Status" char,
                "Install Date" char  
                 ) 
          )
          LOCATION
           ( "INFO":'device_data_week3.csv'   ---csv file
           )
        );
```

And made a procedure to **load data from External Table to the Final Table**, were I also include the actual date time when the data has moved.

```
     Procedure Move_External_Final AS 
        v_upload_date DATE := SYSDATE;
        v_company varchar(1) := '1';  
      BEGIN
       BEGIN

        INSERT INTO SMART_MAP
          (DATA_DATE,
           COMPANY,
           "Serial Number",
           "Status",
           "Install Date"
           )
           SELECT 
            v_upload_date,
            v_company,
            "Serial Number",
            "Status", 
            to_date("Install Date")

        from DEVICE_EXTERNAL    ;  

       COMMIT;

         EXCEPTION
          WHEN no_data_found
            THEN 
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'EXC FAIL INSERT');
       END ;  
      END Move_External_Final;
```

The aim is to leave everything automated. Therefore **I would like to create a procedure that allows the External Table to collect data from the *csv file* and then move this data to the Final Table**.

*Note*: The **csv file** will be **different** every week. Therefore, the external table **old content must be deleted before** collecting the new data.

My question is: **Is it possible to create a procedure to delete previous content and collect data from the csv file to an External table?**

Maybe there is an easier way...

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Create [MATERIALIZE VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302) on you external table and perform complete refresh every time a new file arrives.

If there is some *file naming schema*, so that the file names changes, perfom additionally before the refresh an [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables013.htm#ADMIN11706) to adjust the file name(s) LOCATION.

E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE xxx
   LOCATION ('my_new_file');
```

With MATERIALIZE VIEW you need no procedure to refresh the data, simple call

```
  dbms_mview.refresh('my_materialzed_view','C');
```

Behind the scene a TRUNCATE followed by INSERT APPEND from the external table is performed.